# Store and retrieve Set from localStorage

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set, local-storage

I have the following code that creates a `Set`

```
var foo = new Set();
foo.add(1);
foo.add(2);
```

Now I store it into `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem("set",foo);
```

However If I try to retrieve it like this:

```
var x = localStorage.getItem("set");
```

I get an "[object Set]" as the result.Any Ideas how I can retrieve the actual set?

Comment: use stringify and parse to save object in localstoarge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To store a `Set` you first need to use `JSON.stringify`, which will actually work on object, but to use the same on `Set` you have to first convert it to array.

This is  because data stored in the set is not stored as properties.

```
var foo = new Set();
foo.add(1);
foo.add(2);

// [...foo] is be used as spread operator to convert to array
localStorage.setItem("set",JSON.stringify([...foo]));
var x = localStorage.getItem('set');
console.log('x: ', JSON.parse(x)); // will log [1,2]
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0L0amzs5/)

Comment: It should be noticed that `[...foo]` won't work as expected in some implementations, notably Typescript ES5 target. A safer alternative is Array.from.

Comment: Yes I agree on this

Comment: `notably TypeScript` - he asked for help for ES6, not for TypeScript

Comment: @NonPolynomial Typescript is a superset of ES6 and `tsc` can be used as a transpiler. In the perfect world we have native ES6 implementations. In a real world we use transpilers and need to keep this in mind, to avoid 'why this doesn't work while it should' kind of problems. The asker didn't specify the scenario of use, and the question is not for the asker alone.

Comment: If data are not stored as properties then how are they stored?

Answer (score 4):

In order to do that, a set should be converted to an array first.

It can be done by using ES6 iteration:

```
const fooArr = [...foo];
```

Or if the code is supposed to be transpiled to ES5, it better should be `Array.from`, because it is easily polyfillable. Then it can be stringified and stored:

```
const fooArr = Array.from(foo);
localStorage.setItem('set', JSON.stringify(fooArr));
```

And retrieved in reverse:

```
const fooArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('set'));
const foo = new Set(...fooArr);
```

Comment: If you downvote the correct answer, a good thing is to elaborate on your decision in comment.